# How CustomUser login view should be realised

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I have custom user model `MyUser`

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):                                   
        email = models.EmailField(_('email adress'),unique=True)
```

I created login form `CustomAuthenticationForm` which inherit from built-in `AuthenticationForm`

```
from django import forms                                    
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm                                 
from .models import MyUser

class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('email',)
```

Now i want to create login view where i can check user inputed credentials and authenticate user. To accomplish this task i bit confused by misunderstanding how to properly do it.

```
def login(request):                                            
      if request.method == 'POST':
           form = CustomAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
             email = form.cleaned_data['email']
             password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            #how to check that user inputed    
            #data is valid. Is AuthenticationForm have any method to check password validness

             user = authenticate(email=email,password=password)
      else:
          form = CustomAuthenticationForm()                       
     return render(request,'registration/loginn.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is my question is in built-in `AuthenticationForm` have any method which provide functionality to check user password validity. If no can anyone suggest any appropriate solution to check password than authenticate user

Comment: Check documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you create a custom User in django you must also specify that in the settings by overriding `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Let's suppose your new user model is in `users` app then in settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = users.MyUser
```

And then everywhere you need your user model, try to import it like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Now coming back to your question, django has couple of validations for password, you can add or remove them in the settings file or can even introduce custom. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) for that.